# Cache decorator for FastAPI

Tags: python-3.x, caching, redis, fastapi, decorator

I have a FastAPI route.

```
from functools import wraps

@router.get("/query/", status_code=200,)
async def query(q: str):

    # Grab info from database using query string.

    return res
```

The above is simplified but is accurate to what I generally want to do with various functions in my FastAPI project. I've created the following Python decorator, I believe this is what it should be but I'm not sure.

```
def cache(func):

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # Cache URL

    return wrapper
```

I'm using a Redis instance to cache the URLs from my FastAPI routes. Though, I can't figure out how to get the URL from the `@router` decorator and use the `q` parameter from my function. So for example, how can I get the `"/query/"` part and the value of `q: str` and use it my decorator. There might be a way through storing the URL in a variable and maybe passing it to each decorator, but I'm looking for the intended way to do things. In other words, how can I do this most concisely without changing all my functions too much?